# Is there a way to reuse a knowledge base rather than re-inserting all facts with stateless knowledge sessions?

Tags: java, drools

I have a service that is receiving about 10k messages a minute and I need to process these real-time. To process these I need several thousand facts in the knowledge base.

Initially I was using a stateful knowledge session in which I loaded these facts. I would insert a message, run the rules, retract the message, and repeat. This functioned fine, but the performance was not enough.

I need this process to be multi-threaded, and for that I understand I need stateless sessions. The problem I'm having with stateless sessions is that for every message I process I now need to re-insert these few thousand facts to the knowledge base.

Since the only facts that are changing between most runs are the new messages, I was hoping I could have an initial knowledge base loaded with the other(non-message) facts that each of my stateless sessions can begin with, and then I would just need to load the message itself to each, like I did with stateful.

Is this possible?

I'm using batch insert, and from what I can tell this does not seem to really be killing my performance, but it still seems wrong to have to reinsert these few thousand facts 10k times a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, a stateless session just wraps a stateful session and removes some functionality from it (i.e. you can't pop things in and out).

Inserting a lot of facts is generally a slow process. There is no mechanism to load them fast into a new session. Insert-evaluate-retract solutions can be pretty fast, as they enable you to force the engine to balance itself against the initial 10k facts, so additional facts cause minimal re-evaluation.

To be multi-threaded doesn't mean that you need to go stateless. I would recommend just creating a pool of stateful sessions, with your initial 10k facts already inserted. You just need a little bit of extra logic to ensure that whenever one of those base facts is altered, you alter all of the sessions (it doesn't sound like that's happening frequently). Obviously this will make your application a bit more of a memory hog, but it's a simple way of scaling up.

And you don't say how slow it was with stateful sessions. I have taken a Drools application with 30sec response times and got it providing hundreds of responses in less than a second. I don't know how awesome your DRL coding skills are, so as far as I know, it could just be that you need to do some rules re-writes. Maybe that's food for a separate question. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why I was laboring under the apparently false assumption that stateful knowledge sessions were not thread safe.

Comment: When working with stateless the performance was indeed significantly improved by re-writing the DRLs. I removed all "exists" statements and replaced them with Java methods. So I expect the stateful to be much better now even without the pool. With the pool I'm now hopeful it will be even better than what I'm seeing with stateless.